# How to move my save game to another PC?

Tags: windows-10, raft

I have a new PC and want to move my Raft saved game. Just copy/paste doesn't seem to work. I'm not using any digital platform or service.

Comment: What exactly is the location of your saved game folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the load screen you have

- Open World Folder Path

There you will find the save folder and can copy and paste to your new location

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you claim to not have it on Steam, you likely downloaded the game when it was available on [itch.io](https://itch.io/t/58397/save-game-files), back in 2016, [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raft_(video_game)).

The saved games location for that early version is in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Raft\Raft\SavedGames`.

Copy/pasting should work, according to multiple comments I've seen ([most](https://www.reddit.com/r/raft/comments/kr3tgw/can_someone_help_i_want_to_transfer_my_world_to/) [were](https://www.reddit.com/r/RaftTheGame/comments/a6vewn/can_you_get_someone_else_world_and_download_it/) [about](https://www.reddit.com/r/RaftTheGame/comments/o7j2fi/is_it_possible_to_transfer_my_save_to_my_friend/) the Steam version, but [at least one](https://itch.io/t/55488/location-of-save-files-rgd#:%7E:text=To%20find%20your%20save%20files,when%20you%20run%20the%20game.) wasn't). Make sure you have the same game version on both PCs, and make sure you have the exact folder structure on both ends.